# Ordering data with characters and numeric values (characters first followed by numbers)

Tags: r

I have a df and I wish to order it the following way, with any character values at the begining then followed by any numeric values, is there any way to do this. I have seen a suggestion of splitting the strings into numeric and non-numeric and then pasting back together but wanted to know it was possible without splitting the data?

string = c("main2", "backup", 11, 2, 7, 22, 5, 60, 4, 8, 15, 10, 1, 9, "main")

to return;

string = c("main", "main2", "backup", 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 22, 60)

Comment: Whats the logic behind `backup` being last?

Comment: I know this looks a bit off topic, but I think it is hard to think of this a "tidy" way of handling data. This looks a bit like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Maybe if you share upstream and downstream operations and objectives, we can help even more

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way (although since your vector has been converted to a string vector the numbers are sorted in string sort)

```
> x=c("main2", "backup", 11, 2, 7, 22, 5, 60, 4, 8, 15, 10, 1, 9, "main")
> x[order(!grepl("[a-zA-Z]",x),x)]
 [1] "backup" "main"   "main2"  "1"      "10"     "11"     "15"     "2"      "22"     "4"     
[11] "5"      "60"     "7"      "8"      "9"
```

Another option to get the correct number sort

```
> x[order(!grepl("\\D",x),gsub(" ","0",sprintf(paste0("%0",max(nchar(x)),"s"),x)))]
 [1] "main"   "main2"  "backup" "1"      "2"      "4"      "5"      "7"      "8"      "9"     
[11] "10"     "11"     "15"     "22"     "60"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is challenging because you seem to have an input vector consisting of both strings and numbers.  The expected output is also a mixed vector, and you expect the strings to appear first, sorted lexicographically, with the numbers last, sorted numerically.  Here is one approach:

```r
string = c("main2", "backup", 11, 2, 7, 22, 5, 60, 4, 8, 15, 10, 1, 9, "main")
string[order(-grepl("\\D", string),   # sort text first, integers last
       ifelse(!grepl("\\D", string),
              formatC(string,  width=12, format="d", flag="0"),
              string))]

[1] "backup" "main"   "main2"  "1"      "2"      "4"      "5"      "7"
[9] "8"      "9"      "10"     "11"     "15"     "22"     "60"
```

In the call above to `ifelse`, we left pad the integers with zero so that they will sort numerically as text.  For non numbers, they sort lexicographically as well.

Comment: You did split the data though in ifelse, and OP asked for a solution without splitting.

Comment: The OP did not actually define what "splitting" the data means.  Well, I am using a 2 level sort, and I don't see much way around that.

Comment: Yep sorry I didn't specify very clearly. By splitting i meant splitting the data out and holding it in 2 temporary data sets before pasting back together, so this method is fine, i just didn't have any luck replicating

Answer (score 2):

Negate each number and then use `mixedsort` and then at the end remove the minus signs we added.

```
library(gtools)

sub("-", "", mixedsort(sub("(\\d)", "-\\1", string), TRUE))

##  [1] "main"   "main2"  "backup" "1"      "2"      "4"      "5"      "7"     
##  [9] "8"      "9"      "10"     "11"     "15"     "22"     "60"
```

This is pipe friendly and could be expressed as

```
string |>
  sub("(\\d)", "-\\1", x = _) |>
  mixedsort(TRUE) |>
  sub("-", "", x = _)

##  [1] "main"   "main2"  "backup" "1"      "2"      "4"      "5"      "7"     
##  [9] "8"      "9"      "10"     "11"     "15"     "22"     "60"
```

### Update

Found a shorter and more pipe friendly way to do this than with my original `mixedsort` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mixedsort()` to concatenate based on indexing whether or not the value is a number (using `as.numeric()`:

```
c(
  gtools::mixedsort(string[is.na(as.numeric(string))], decreasing = TRUE),
  gtools::mixedsort(string[!is.na(as.numeric(string))])
)

# [1] "main"   "main2"  "backup" "1"      "2"      "4"      "5"      "7"      "8"      "9"      "10"     "11"     "15"     "22"     "60"
```